# Opening 90 million lines of text from a .txt file

Tags: vb.net, text, out-of-memory

I am having problems in opening 90 million lines of text from a .txt file and adding them in the array, it is giving me an error and it prevents it from opening. Here is my code:

```
Dim Contents As String()
Contents = File.ReadAllLines(RichTextBox4.Text)
```

I have tried 1 million lines of text and it works, but when i tried over 90 million lines it is now giving me an error. Is there any alternative for this? Thanks in advance.

additional info:

These 90 million lines acts as a filter which prevents the user from inputting if the word they input exists in one of the 90 million lines. That is my main goal.

Comment: what's the error? outofmemoryexception?

Comment: yes that error pops up

Comment: That means you don't have enough RAM to hold the 90 million lines of code.  You'll have to process the lines in batches.

Comment: Please post the error, why 90 million lines? can't you split it in multiple more files at the source (eg. appending _n° at the end of the file name)? Are you loading it in arichtextbox and then copy it into an array?

Comment: @ps2goat not necessary... it more often means 32bit process and even 16GB of RAM will not make process' address space any bigger. But indeed processing 90 million strings better be done sequentially/in batches/...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov what isn't necessary?  I didn't tell him to get more RAM, I just said there wasn't enough to do them all at once in-memory.

Comment: @ps2goat OOM does not necessary "means you don't have enough RAM"...  sorry for confusion. (unless as "RAM" you mean "address space of the process").

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest using a steam reader and read a single line each time and then handle that and then read the next line while 'throwing away' the old line.

That way you do not need to read every single line into memory but only the working line.

Comment: I want all lines to be stored in an array, but i think array can't handle 90 million lines.

Comment: Why do you want it in the array?

Comment: I want to call these 90 million lines as reference within the program itself.

Comment: it's faster to go to the disk each time as needed, or better yet, use a database.  90 million anything is too much to keep track of while still trying to create a good user experience within the app.

Comment: I agree with ps2goat. 
It would be better to use alternate storage and lookup data on demand, than trying to load every piece of data into the application at start - especially if you're talking that amount of data.

Comment: I am confused on what to do. Should I give up using a text file as storage for these 90 million lines and find another alternative?

Comment: Yes, that would be a good direction in my view. Many small database systems exists.
However you can still keep it as text, or even XML, but you'll need to read from the file each time to get the data you need, and not pull all the data into memory.
Common for all solutions however is that you shouldn't read all the data in at startup unless you have a dedicated system to handle it. Data should generally speaking be fetched on demand, lest it's a caching system.

However to give more advice, I'd recommend starting a specific question about how to design your system :)

Comment: These 90 million lines acts as a filter which prevents the user from inputting if the word they input exists in one of the 90 million lines. That is my main goal.

Comment: Now, I'm more intrigued. What type of information do you have in those 90 million lines which a user must not input? I've never met such a scope of that requirement before. That's a massive amounts of data after all if you'll need to filter that out of apparently free text user input?

Comment: Just random words i have generated within the program itself. This is just an experiment and i want to implement this feature of filter detection.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39887/discussion-between-marc-intes-and-allan-s-hansen)

Answer (score 1):

You can read the huge file in chunks and save each chunk on the disk for later reference.

You can get the underlying file stream and then do something like that:

```
Dim stream = reader.BaseStream
```

then use the stream seek method to move the file pointer

```
stream.Seek(CHUNK_SIZE, SeekOrigin.[Start])
```

Comment: Is there anyway that i could store these 90 million lines like an array? because I want to call them within my program as reference.

Comment: You can do that, but it will consume a lot of memory though.
you can keep adding the chunks your read to a list of strings and finally convert it to an array

Comment: Yes I can't risk it. I am trying to make my application less resource hog as possible. I want it to be lightweight so it will have a low system requirement.

Comment: It's better (memory-wise at least) to keep the file on the disk and read it chunk by chunk whenever it is required. No need to load the entire file in memory in my opinion.